# JAX-WS - Map Exceptions to faults

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am using JAX WS to expose a WebService. Some of the operations of this service can generate exceptions. Not internal server exceptions, but rather exceptions that are dependent on the  input arguments of the operation invocation.

If I specify that my operation throws a custom Exception, like so:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use = Use.LITERAL)
public class MyServiceEndpointImpl implements MyServiceEndpoint {

    @WebMethod
    public void throwsException throws InvalidInputException;
}
```

I end up with the following stacktrace when running the application:

```
 com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class com.mypackage.ws.services.jaxws.InvalidInputExceptionBean is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getClass(RuntimeModeler.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processExceptions(RuntimeModeler.java:1006)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processRpcMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:969)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:370)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:467)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:121)
```

Adding `@XmlRootEntity` to `InvalidInputException` does not solve the problem.

If this is not the recommended way to report faults over web services, then is there a better way? Should my exceptions inherit from `RuntimeException` and rely on the transport for the error handling (i.e., everything will end up wrapped in a SOAPException)? I was hoping for something like Spring-WS' `SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver`. Is there something similar at all available for JAX-WS?

Comment: Perhaps I should note that the class it reports as missing, com.mypackage.ws.services.jaxws.InvalidInputExceptionBean, indeed does not exist. But I assumed that was natural, that it should be generated like the exception states.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Did you try to annotate your exception with [`@WebFault`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebFault.html)? Also, do you implement `getFaultInfo()`?

**EDIT:** I realize my answer was maybe not detailed enough. As reminded in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14083314) (for example):

> The JAX-WS 2.0 specification demands
>   that the exception annotated with
>   `@WebFault` must have two constructors
>   and one method [getter to obtain the fault information]:
>
> ```
> WrapperException(String message, FaultBean faultInfo)
> WrapperException(String message, FaultBean faultInfo, Throwable cause)
> FaultBean getFaultInfo()
> ```
>
> The `WrapperException` is replaced by
>   the name of the exception, and
>   `FaultBean` is replaced by the class
>   name that implements the fault bean.
>   The fault bean is a Java bean that
>   contains the information of the fault
>   and is used by the Web service client
>   to know the cause for the fault.

This is detailed in section 2.5 Fault of the JAX-WS specification. Does your exception conform to this? Can you post the code?

---

The OP is right. As per specification 2.1, section 3.7 Service Specific Exception, it is not required to use the `@WebFault` annotation, JAX-WS can generate the wrapper beans dynamically for exceptions that do not match the pattern described in section 2.5 (just provide a getter for the information you want to be present in the fault). For exceptions that match the pattern described in section 2.5 (i.e. exceptions that have a `getFaultInfo` method and `@WebFault` annotation), the *FaultBean* is used as input to JAXB when mapping the exception to XML Schema.

So the solution suggested above (matching the pattern described in section 2.5) is only a workaround. The generation of wrapper beans should just work for other exceptions. And I don't know why this fails here.

Comment: I did not. I tried that now, but I get the same error. But do I need to specify @WebFault's properties name, targetNameSpace and faultBean as well?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will look into it. No, I did not implement the constructors you indicated. I read (misread?) that part of the specification as the JAX WS implementation would *automatically generate* the exception wrapper itself with those constructors. I am beginning to think I am doing something backwards...

Comment: It turns out that conforming to the Exception style you wrote above means that JAX-WS will *not* create a wrapper bean for the exception, which it otherwise should. So that works as a workaround for me. However, it *should* work with all exceptions without annotations, according to "3.7 Service Specific Exception" in the spec.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent - Everytime I look for an answer I find you. Maybe I should just resign and you can do my job? :)

Comment: @PascalThivent : it seems that even in JAX-WS 2.0 the `getFaultInfo` was optional. At the end of section 3.7 the same sample mapping can be found as in spec version 2.1. It doesn't seem widely supported though.

Answer (score 17):

An addition to the answer above. I ended up with this as my InvalidInputException implementation:

```
@WebFault(faultBean = "com.mypackage.ws.exception.FaultBean")
public class InvalidInputException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private FaultBean faultBean;

    public InvalidInputException() {
        super();
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String message, FaultBean faultBean, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultBean = faultBean;
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String message, FaultBean faultBean) {
        super(message);
        this.faultBean = faultBean;
    }

    public FaultBean getFaultInfo() {
        return faultBean;
    }
}
```

And `FaultBean` is just a simple POJO with currently no data at all. Now, according to the JAX-WS specification (see 3.7 Service Specific Exception), it conforms to what is required of an exception annotated with @WebFault, so it will not create a wrapper bean for it, which probably is what was failing.

This is a decent workaround, but it does not explain the error in the question.

Comment: +1 for this, it saved my day :). But this is only working for checked Exceptions not for unchecked Exceptions. Any clues...

Comment: @waxwing I have implemented an example however my example doesn't work without defining targetNamespace element?

Comment: @rits Well same happened to me I tried this on Websphere 8.5.5 which has Axis 2 as a service provider for JAX-WS and it didn't work with RuntimeException, but it did work doing the same with Websphere Liberty Profile because it uses Apache CXF instead. It's a shame actually because now my client need to catch/declare the exception.