# Specifying jaxb version to wsgen

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm suffering from the same error as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232331/unable-to-create-jaxbcontext-creating-my-wsdl/15072778#15072778), but I can't use that answer since I'm not using Maven, so I'm stuck on how to specify what version of jaxb to use with wsgen. I'm downloaded the 2.2.7 jars and added them to my classpath, but my generated files still say that they've been generated using 2.2.4b1, which I presume was included in the JDK.

Anybody know how to specify to wsgen what jaxb version I want to use?

Comment: you could set the runtime's classpath of wsgen within your IDE or by command line. Of course in that classpath you will put the correct implementation jar version

Comment: BTW looking here does not seem possible to specify versions: https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.1/docs/wsgenant.html