# Is JDK8 a supported platform for JBoss 6 AS

Tags: java-8, jboss6.x

We are upgrading our application java platform to latest stable one and we are using Jboss 6 AS.

Is **Oracle JDK8** a supported platform for JBoss 6 AS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think no
JBoss AS7 Supported with JDK8 | JBoss Developer 
check this 
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/238195?_sscc=t

Comment: UPDATE : Initially i got some error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232331/unable-to-create-jaxbcontext-creating-my-wsdl while upgrading later after resolving i was able to run JBoss 6 AS on jdk8 platform But support config doc says like it won't support.

Answer (score 4):

No. Its not going to work. `JBoss AS 6` and 7 are not compatible with `Oracle JDK 1.8`. You need to download WildFly 10 in order to work with `JDK 1.8`.

`WildFly` is formerly knows as `JBoss AS`