# throwing exceptions->faults from SOAP service Java with GlassFish

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, glassfish, faults

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JAX-WS - Map Exceptions to faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064447/jax-ws-map-exceptions-to-faults)

I do not normally use java, but I being forced to write a service wrapper around a 3rd party library that I need. (So I can call it from c#)

I am using NetBeans with GlassFish, and I was wondering how to work with SOAP Faults in there.

```
  @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
  public String hello() throws Exception
  {
    return "Hello World!";
  }
```

How do I change this so that any exceptions thrown inside hello() get turned into Faults?  Even a single fault that just contains the exception message will do for now.

I really just have no idea how to deal with faults in this environment... any information will help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064447/jax-ws-map-exceptions-to-faults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String hello() {
  try {
    return "Hello World";
  } catch(Exception e) {
    // Throw the fault here.
  }
}
```

Look here for more:

[JAX-WS - Map Exceptions to faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064447/jax-ws-map-exceptions-to-faults)

Comment: okay but what is "// Throw the fault here." - that's the part I have no idea where to start

Comment: yes, korifey's answer worked.  wish i could assign him as the answer