# Web Services Exception

Tags: java, web-services, exception, fault

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I have developed some Web Services with Netbeans in Linux and they work just fine (with Tomcat). I can call the services with SOAPUI and everything looks good.
The problem arises when I build a WAR file and try to deploy it in a Tomcat installation over Windows. Then I get this:

```
...
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed
Sep 17, 2012 4:28:08 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
Sep 17, 2012 4:28:09 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:201)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1255)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at public java.lang.Throwable[] my.org.jaxws.MyExceptionBean.suppressed
        at umy.org.jaxws.MyExceptionBean

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at public java.lang.Throwable[] my.org.jaxws.MyExceptionBean.suppressed
        at my.org.jaxws.MyExceptionBean

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:154)
    ... 40 more
```

So I guess there is a problem with the exception I raise in a service:

```
@WebMethod(...)
public ..... throws Exception {
 if ()...
 else
    throw new MyException(); // extends java.lang.Exception
}
```

First thing I do not understand is why this works fine in my Netbeans Tomcat over Linux and not in the Windows Tomcat I have installed.
I have checked some information:

- [JAX-WS - Map Exceptions to faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064447/jax-ws-map-exceptions-to-faults)
- [Unable to create JAXBContext creating my wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232331/unable-to-create-jaxbcontext-creating-my-wsdl)
- [SOAP faults](http://io.typepad.com/eben_hewitt_on_java/2009/07/using-soap-faults-and-exceptions-in-java-jaxws-web-services.html)
- [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-jaxws-faults/index.html)

And see more other Websites. It is not clear for me what to do. Some webs advice to use a "workaround" including the @WebFault and create additional methods in the class and a dummy POJO class. I have many exceptions and seems a lot of work. Some suggest to remove a JAR (I do not really have) from the classpath. I am still wondering what I have in my Netbeans Tomcat that is not in my Windows Tomcat. I am quite new in this.

Is there an easy way to solve this? Many thanks.

**==== EDIT ====**

As suggested in some answers, I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
@XmlTransient
    @Override
    public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace() {
        return super.getStackTrace();
    }

    @XmlTransient
    @Override
    public Throwable getCause() {
        return super.getCause();
    }
```

Also, if I use @WebFault, I get another exception (this time even on Linux):

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processExceptions(RuntimeModeler.java:1162)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:898)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:666)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:420)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:254)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:338)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:521)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1359)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:857)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:795)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:849)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:351)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

I have tried to implement the messageName() but nothing worked.
I have followed the indications of other questions but does not work. The code is:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "InputMessageValidationFaultType")
public class FaultBean {

@XmlAttribute
    protected String message;

    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

}




import javax.xml.ws.WebFault;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@WebFault(faultBean = "FaultBean")
public class MyException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private FaultBean faultBean;

    public  MyException(){
        super();
    }

    public  MyException( String message , FaultBean faultBean , Throwable cause){
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultBean = faultBean;
    }    

    public  MyException( String message, FaultBean faultBean ){
        super(message);
        this.faultBean = faultBean;
    }    

    public FaultBean getFaultInfo() {
        return faultBean;
    }

}
```

It is still strange for me that everything works just fine on my Netbeans/Tomcat/Linux and fails when I move the WAR to the Tomcat/Windows....

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception. In my case, the fix was to upgrade Java from 1.6 to 1.7. After that, the war file worked correctly.