# Unable to create jaxb context - WebFault error

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

Error at method initiateBatchProcess : unreported exception must be caught or declared to be thrown. I have a custom exception class with @webFault annotation to handle jaxb exception as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064447/jax-ws-map-exceptions-to-faults).

My `initiateBatchProcess()` method is already extending custom exception class but still its showing error

```
@WebService(serviceName = "WT_WebService")
public class WT
{    
    ResponseInfo result = new ResponseInfo();

    @WebMethod(operationName = "initiateBatchProcess")
      public @WebResult(name = "Response") ArrayList initiateBatchProcess(@WebParam (name = "BatchID")int BatchId, @WebParam (name = "MPTRef")String MPTRef) throws MyServiceException
      {
          return result.initiateBatchProcess();
      }
```

Custom Exception class:

```
@WebFault(name="MyServiceException", faultBean = "com.ws.MyServiceFault", targetNamespace="http://wataniya.com/")
public class MyServiceException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private MyServiceFault faultBean;

    public MyServiceException() {
        super();
    }

    public MyServiceException(String message, MyServiceFault faultBean, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultBean = faultBean;
    }

    public MyServiceException(String message, MyServiceFault faultBean) {
        super(message);
        this.faultBean = faultBean;
    }

    public MyServiceFault getFaultInfo() {
        return faultBean;
    }
}
```

FaultBean class:

```
public class MyServiceFault {
    /**
     * Fault Code
     */
     private String faultCode;
     /**
      * Fault String
      */
     private String faultString;
    /**
     * @return the faultCode
     */
    public String getFaultCode() {
        return faultCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param faultCode the faultCode to set
     */
    public void setFaultCode(String faultCode) {
        this.faultCode = faultCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the faultString
     */
    public String getFaultString() {
        return faultString;
    }
    /**
     * @param faultString the faultString to set
     */
    public void setFaultString(String faultString) {
        this.faultString = faultString;
    }

}
```

ResponseInfo Class:

```
public class ResponseInfo
{    
    static Properties props = new Properties();

    public ArrayList initiateBatchProcess() throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList list  = new ArrayList();
        props.load(ResponseInfo.class.getResourceAsStream("ResponseFields.properties"));
        String method1_status = props.getProperty("method1_status");
        String method1_comments = props.getProperty("method1_comments");
        list.add(method1_status);
        list.add(method1_comments);
        return list;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What about ResponseInfo.initiateBatchProcess() method, does it throw any other exception but MyServiceException?

Comment: It throws only unreported exception

Comment: Could you provide sources for ResponseInfo class cause so far I don't see any problem with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResponseInfo.initiateBatchProcess()` declares to throw a checked exception `Exception` but it's not handled in `WT.initiateBatchProcess()`.

Your have either to declare `WT.initiateBatchProcess()` to throw `Exception` or catch `Exception` and rethrow it as `MyServiceException`(that could be done either in ResponseInfo or in WT class).

**EDIT**: second option implementation would look like this:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "initiateBatchProcess")
  public @WebResult(name = "Response") ArrayList initiateBatchProcess(@WebParam (name = "BatchID")int BatchId, @WebParam (name = "MPTRef")String MPTRef) throws MyServiceException
  {
      ArrayList returnValue = null;
      try {
          returnValue = result.initiateBatchProcess();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new MyServiceException(e);
      }

      return returnValue;
  }
```

I've added a `MyServiceException(Exception e)` constructor for simplicity but you could modify the code according to your needs.

Comment: How do I create a constructor for `MyServiceException(e)` as it is giving me error.

Comment: Here's what I've used:
       `public MyServiceException(Exception e) {
  super(e);
 }`

Comment: But of course you could use `MyServiceException(String message, MyServiceFault faultBean, Throwable cause)` constructor. In this case you would need to create and populate `faultBean`.